# php - append value to array from array if values matches

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a way, with the two followings arrays  to get another array which is the combination of those two arrays?

Array 1:

```
    Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [a_id] => 9
        [name] => Mario Lopez
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [a_id] => 8
        [name] => Lisa Turtle
    )

)
```

Array 2:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [b_id] => 1
        [name] => AC Slater
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [b_id] => 2
        [name] => Lisa Turtle
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [b_id] => 3
        [name] => Kelly Kapowski
    )
)
```

What I would like to get :

```
    Array
    (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [b_id] => 1
            [name] => AC Slater
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [a_id] => 8
            [b_id] => 2
            [name] => Lisa Turtle
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [b_id] => 3
            [name] => Kelly Kapowski
        )
     [3] => Array
        (
            [a_id] => 9
            [name] => Mario Lopez
        )
    )
```

The third array merges the two first arrays where the key name matches
I have not found a [builtin function](http://php.net/manual/fr/ref.array.php) and tried this solution without success: [combine 2 associative arrays where values match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703769/combine-2-associative-arrays-where-values-match).

Thank you,

Edit: sorry, I forgot to add Mario Lopez.
My attempt was:

```
function array_extend($a, $b) {
    foreach($b as $k=>$v) {
        if( is_array($v) ) {
            if( !isset($a[$k]) OR isset($v[0])) {
                $a[$k] = $v;
            } else {
                $a[$k] = array_extend($a[$k], $v);
            }
        } else {
            $a[$k] = $v;
        }
    }
    return $a;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "tried this solution without success"? Please show your attempt and explain what is wrong with it. Thanks.

Comment: where will `Mario Lopez` become ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably is what you are looking for, although as @OldPadawan already pointed out in the comments to the question the actual result differs from the proposed one...

```
<?php
$a = [
    [
        'a_id' => 9,
        'name' => 'Mario Lopez'
    ],
    [
        'a_id' => 8,
        'name' => 'Lisa Turtle'
    ]
];
$b = [
    [
        'b_id' => 1,
        'name' => 'AC Slater'
    ],
    [
        'b_id' => 2,
        'name' => 'Lisa Turtle'
    ],
    [
        'b_id' => 3,
        'name' => 'Kelly Kapowski'
    ]
];
$c = $a;
array_walk($b, function($be) use (&$c) {
    $done = false;
    array_walk($c, function(&$ce) use($be, &$done) {
        if ($ce['name'] == $be['name']) {
            $ce['b_id'] = $be['b_id'];
            $done = true;
        }
    });
    if ( ! $done) {
        array_push($c, $be);
    }
});
print_r($c);
```

The output of above code is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [a_id] => 9
            [name] => Mario Lopez
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [a_id] => 8
            [name] => Lisa Turtle
            [b_id] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [b_id] => 1
            [name] => AC Slater
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [b_id] => 3
            [name] => Kelly Kapowski
        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you arkascha. indeed I made a mistake.